# mod_proxy tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mod-proxy, http-status-code-404

I've asked this question in a few places and I've found no answer. It *should* be pretty simple and a pretty common problem.  Unfortunately I know nothing about tomcat and mod_proxy so I'm unable to figure it out.

I have a few apps running in tomcat, installed as wars and I can access them at
`myserver.com:8080/myapp`

I simply want to create an apache vhost that forwards *myapp.myserver.com* to this *myserver.com:8080/myapp* using mod_proxy.

Hudson is a perfect example, there's no extra config, just a deployed war.  So I set up the following apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hudson.myserver.ca

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/hudson
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/hudson

</VirtualHost>
```

and my proxy.conf is:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyRequests Off

  <Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  # Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
  # ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
  # Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block

  ProxyVia On
</IfModule>
```

Every request on every app has the same behavior.  I go to hudson.myserver.ca for example, and it for some reason forwards on to hudson.myserver.ca/hudson, which gives a tomcat 404 that says

`The requested resource (/hudsonhudson/) is not available.`

happens for hudson, jira, confluence, and any other app.

What's with the extra 'hudson' and why isn't this working?

Comment: What URL are you going to that gets that?  What do the logs say?

Comment: as mentioned, the url is `hudson.myserver.ca`.  Logs say:
hudson.myserver.ca:80 206.248.167.169 - - [20/Oct/2009:18:57:36 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.3 Safari/531.9"

hudson.myserver.ca:80 206.248.167.169 - - [20/Oct/2009:18:57:36 -0400] "GET /hudson/ HTTP/1.1" 404 389 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.3 Safari/531.9"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proxy configuration should read:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/hudson/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/hudson/
```

Then, you need to find out what is causing the `302` redirect in the first instance. There might be a rewrite rule somewhere else that is causing it.

On another note, you may want to consider using *mod_proxy_ajp* instead for Tomcat connections simply because that is what it was made for.

Comment: Ah, so the trailing / after my proxypass was causing the problem (or lack thereof rather)  Adding that properly proxied.  However, the stylesheets aren't loaded properly as they all are linked with /hudson.  So do I need a rewrite rule here?

Comment: yup, 
RewriteRule       ^/hudson(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/hudson$1 [P,L]
did the trick, thx again!