# Need to know how to route non 80 port to a sub domain

Tags: domain, subdomain, dedicated-server, port-forwarding

I have my domain hosted in my own server. There are two applications running on my server that are accessible via `example.com` (IIS on port 80) and `example.com:8080` (Tomcat on port 8080).

Now I would like to create a subdomain like `myapp.example.com` and make the `example.com:8080` available in it so that the user need not specify the port to accesa the app.

Is it possible to do?

Please give me some guidance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/76539/mod-proxy-tomcat which has the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your IIS version, [IIS can act as a reverse proxy](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx) for version 
7.0 and above.

If you are using IIS below 7, it'd be better to run your IIS on ports
other than 80, and then [setup a reverse proxy with apache](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/06/multiple-web-servers-over-a-single-ip-using-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy/) that run on
port 80.